# How can I generically map query results to a generated XML?

Tags: java, xml, resultset

This is the query:

```
Select id, title, value, old_title, old_value, new_title, new_value FROM VALUES
```

This the XML:

```
<row>
  <id>
  <title>
  <value>
  <old_state>
    <title>
    <value>
  </old_state>
  <new_state>
    <title>
    <value>
  </new_state>
<row>
```

The way I do it for existing XML is that I don't have the `new_state`/`old_state` so I can just use the result, eg. `String colName = meta.getColumnLabel(i + 1);` and there is no need to map `old_title` to `title`. Now I have The only thing that comes to mind is to make a map in which the key would be the counter value and the value would be the new element name, like this

```
boolean columnNameIsStartElement = (columStartNames.get(i) != null)?true=false;
boolean columnNameIsEndElement = (columEndNames.get(i) != null)?true=false;
if (columnNameIsStartElement ){
  writer.writeStartElement(columStartNames.get(i))
} else if (columnNameIsEndElement){
  writer.writeEndElement(columStartNames.get(i))
}
//continue processing the element as usual
```

But I don't like it. I would prefer to use the XSD somehow so the solution is more generic and it doesn't require me to count the lines of elements so I can map them correctly (not to mention the problems I'll get into if a child element has an additional child, how could I map that? :))

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/), it allows to do that kind of mappings easily.

---

Edit: Ok, so if you're that strict on output format, and you don't want intermediate objects then you could consider using Velocity. You'd just need to write a small template from your sample output, and call velocity passing it your ResultSet in its Context.

Comment: Looks good but I write from the resultset to XML, there is no Object in between because I think that would create additional load.

Comment: Also, if I have a selected item "old_value" I need it as "old_value" in the XML, not as "oldValue".

Answer (score 0):

You could use Castor to bind your query result into XML. Look at this example: http://www.castor.org/jdo.html#Using-JDO-And-XML